# Regular expression prevent double dashes and white space from being entered in textbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, regex

I have come up with a Regular Expression that prevents the user from using two consecutive dashes.  They may enter nearly any other pattern imaginable.  The only other criteria I am trying implement is to prevent the user from entering any white space anywhere in the textbox. Here is my expression that works for preventing double dashes:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:(?!--).)*$", ErrorMessage = "No double dashes please")]
```

Can someone help me add to this expression the ability to prevent the user from enter a space anywhere in the textbox

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To also prevent whitespace you can add `\s` to the existing negative look-ahead using alternation:

```
@"^(?:(?!--|\s).)*$"
```

Comment: Excellent!! It works perfect Thank you. I kept putting the |\s after the asterisk. I would up vote, but I don't have enough rep points.